# How can I use Apps Script to Rename a duplicated tab/sheet with a mix of fixed text AND date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is a report that we want to have keep track of and have a snapshot of each day. Using a Macro recording and getting some scripts from the internet, I was able to make it so that at the end of each day, the Master sheet ("SY 2022/23 IR: Track & Field (Auto;DNE)") gets duplicated, all values are pasted only, and the sheet gets renamed.

The problem I'm running into is that I want each new tab/sheet to be saved with the day's date (i.e. Track & Field IR 1/23/2023). What I've tried...so many things that I'm not familiar with. This AppScript is the best I can get as of now.

Please help, and thank you!

Example worksheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYG0l6jTxLUCNz8kwCiO3H_AhtnvJh6A2pidVMUySeg/edit#gid=520508927

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:I').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SY 2022/23 IR: Track & Field (Auto;DNE)'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Track & Field IR ");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to rename the copied sheet to `Track & Field IR 1/23/2023`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Track & Field IR ");
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Track & Field IR " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy"));
```

#### Note:

- From your script, I thought that your script might be able to be also modified as follows.

  ```
    function sample() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var srcSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SY 2022/23 IR: Track & Field (Auto;DNE)');
      srcSheet.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName("Track & Field IR " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy"));
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=ja#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#copyTo(Spreadsheet))